# how using Webserver in Android with wifi?

Tags: android, asp.net, eclipse, webserver

I have a simple web server in ASP.NET and a application in android(java,eclipse).

I want to send a name from android to webserver, and webserver return `"hello" + name`
when I run Android Appclitaion and send a name to webserver, the program doesn't work.

**webservice**

```
namespace HelloWorldWebService
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string sayHello(string name)
        {
            return "Hello " + name;
        }
    }
}
```

my ip is : `192.168.1.3` - and when I run webserver with visual studio,the address is `localhost:6109/Service.asmx`

Following is the android codes:
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
 Button b;
 TextView tv;
 EditText et;
 ProgressBar pg;
 String editText;
 String displayText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     //Name Text control
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    //Display Text control
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    //Button to trigger web service invocation
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //Display progress bar until web service invocation completes
    pg = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    //Button Click Listener
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (et.getText().length() != 0 && et.getText().toString() != "") {
                //Get the text control value
                editText = et.getText().toString();
                //Create instance for AsyncCallWS
                AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                //Call execute 
                task.execute();
            //If text control is empty
            } else {
                tv.setText("Please enter name");
            }   
        }
    });
}

private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> 
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        displayText = WebService.invokeHelloWorldWS(editText,"sayHello");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        tv.setText(displayText);
        pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;//return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

---

webServer Class:

```
public class WebService {

private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String URL = "http://192.168.1.3:6109/Service.asmx?op=sayHello";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";

public static String invokeHelloWorldWS(String name, String webMethName) {
    String resTxt = null;
    // Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);
    // Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo celsiusPI = new PropertyInfo();
    // Set Name
    celsiusPI.setName("name");
    // Set Value
    celsiusPI.setValue(name);
    // Set dataType
    celsiusPI.setType(String.class);
    // Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(celsiusPI);
    // Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        // Invole web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);
        // Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        // Assign it to fahren static variable
        resTxt = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        resTxt = "Error occured";
    } 

    return resTxt;
}
}
```

Comment: are u running ur application in emulator or a device ?

Comment: run application ---------------> in device -

Comment: does your android application crash on device ?

Comment: no - write in textview:'Error occured'

Comment: connect your phone with the computer, that would enable you to see the stack-trace of your application.

Comment: you can replace the IP address with the address `10.0.2.2` in your application. In emulator `10.0.2.2` refers to your `localhost` You dont have to enable WiFi in emulator.

Also, ADT helps in launching application directly on your device. So all the error logs of your connected device can be read on logCat as well. The error log will help you and us to understand the problem more clearly.